# How can I cure lycanthropy?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I really want to get rid of it. I've been through the whole companion’s quest line and cured Kodlak's. I killed all 5 witches and have 4 of the heads left in my inventory.

I've been back to that same flame and tried to use it with the head, but nothing going; activating it does nothing. I've heard this is how you cure it; however I have not heard a first-hand account of anyone actually curing it.

If you have, can you explain what you do? Do you go to the same tomb where you fought Kodlak's beast form? Do you do something special with the witch head in your inventory, or just have it in there and activate the harbinger flame or whatever?

Answer (score 42):

Well, I cured my own lycanthropy. I noticed there is one vote on this so I am sure that there are people who are still interested in this. I will leave as much detail as possible in the hope of helping people who have this issue in the future.

First of all, yes, the process for curing is exactly the same as how you cure Kodlak. You just have a witch's head in your inventory and examine that blue flame where you fought Kodlak's beast, and the option pops up, something like "Toss a head in the fire and cure your lycanthropy forever?"

Now, this is about the 300th time I'd tried activating that thing, so there is just some serious bug going on here. I think it's probably related to the fact that I spammed that flame the first time I was there during Kodlak's quest.

Here is the circumstance under which it finally worked:

To get the "purity" quest, continue doing random "quests" for Farkas and his brother until they tell you that they want to cure themselves.

I did Farkas and even though I used the flame to cure Farkas, I never got an option to cure myself. Then I did the same thing with his brother. When you have this quest, activating the blue flame causes the beast to come out right away.

After this, I tried to activate it, but nothing happened. Then I spoke to Vilkas and he said something like "Thanks, now I'm going to stay here for a while." After that, I tried the flame again and it worked.

I don't know if it finally working was related to what my actions were or whether it was just some random chance, but know that there is hope for those who think they will be stuck as a werewolf forever. Good luck.

Comment: Like you, I was unable to cure myself until I had cured Vilkas. I have yet to cure Farkas, however, if that helps anyone else any.

Comment: I've done a dozen quests for Vilkas / Farkas and neither is asking to be cured. :( (After finishing main Companion quest line.)

Comment: @ChristopherGalpin I think it's just random, friend. Keep at it!

Answer (score 13):

**Curing Lycanthropy**

*The companions method*

This answer is taken from [the Elder Scrolls Wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Lycanthropy_%28Skyrim%29)

> WARNING: Once Lycanthropy is cured via the  companions method, you
>   cannot contract Lycanthropy again, nor do you  have access to the
>   Underforge. At the end of the Companions questline,  a radiant quest
>   "Purity" becomes available for those who wish to rid  themselves of
>   the disease. As part of that quest, you must cut off the  head of a
>   Glenmoril Witch, bringing it into the depths of Ysgramor's  Tomb, draw
>   the spirit of the wolf from your body, and defeat it.    **In order to
>   remove the curse however, the Dragonborn must have killed  at least
>   two Glenmoril Witches, one for Kodlak, one for the  Dragonborn.** If you
>   kill all 5 witches you can cure all of the The  Circle, except for
>   Aela who does not want to be cured.

*The Vampire Lord method*

With the release of the [Dawnguard DLC](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Elder_Scrolls_V:_Dawnguard) another method has become available to cure Lycanthropy.
All you need to do is get the quest [Bloodline](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Bloodline) and choose to join the vampires.
Becoming a Vampire Lord will remove the Lycanthropy.

Answer (score 6):

In Dawnguard, in addition to the cure above, you can choose to become a Vampire Lord, and that will replace the Lycanthropy with Vampirism.

Note also that in Dawngaurd you can become a Werewolf again, even if you had contracted and cured it previously by speaking to Aela. This is something you may wish to do, as there is a new perk tree for werewolves:

[image]

You can gain points for this tree by consuming the hearts of corpses while a werewolf.

Comment: Can you switch back and forth at will, or are both acts (choosing to become a Vampire Lord, speaking to Aela) one time only?