# In Skyrim, are the Companion quests still available after taking over Whiterun (Stormcloaks path)?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Being completely new to the game, I randomly decided to help take over Whiterun for the Stormcloaks before I got a chance to finish the Companion quests. Does that mean that the Companion quests are no longer available? Are the options to marry the various Companion members still a possibility after taking over Whiterun?

(P.S. I am also wondering if it is possible to cure [lycanthropy, aka being a Werewolf,](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Lycanthropy) after having taken over Whiterun. I know there is a way that involves one of the last Companions quests, hence why I asked if I could still finish that quest line after taking over Whiterun.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can still finish the quests for the Companions - joining the Stormcloaks and taking Whiterun actually has very little impact on practical gameplay, as it mostly just replaces some NPCs with some other NPCs, and some NPCs become happier than some others.

As for the second part of your question, you'll be able to cure yourself of lycanthropy as well, in the same manner that everyone else cures it (if you need a bit of help there, check [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35816/has-anyone-actually-cured-lycanthropy) question out).

Comment: Thank you! That's all I needed to know. I was afraid that the game was TOO good, in that it would completely change the world it's set in by removing entire groups of characters, etc. Good to know the developers allow players to be able to complete quests regardless of which paths they take.

Would it be safe to assume that all quests are always available unless you fail them? Even then they can be re-done I believe. And quest-givers marked as "essential" cannot be killed, only hurt to near-zero health. Makes sense!

Comment: Yeah for almost any "important" (read: leads to another quest, establishes you as a member of a group, etc.) quest, they've made it fairly reality proof. Big change from Morrowind, where you could just break the world at will.

Comment: There is a known bug with the thieves guild sending you to raid a house you can no longer get into after the Whiterun invasion regardless of which side you are on, but it is not a 'main' quest.

Comment: Could you link to the quest? I wouldn't mind knowing what it is...

Comment: @artless, sounds like one of the radiant 'heist' jobs. You can simply cancel those and get a different one. So I doubt there is a real link to the quest. Not sure of course.