# Will people in Whiterun treat me differently if I join the Stormcloaks?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was going to join the Stormcloaks for the Civil War quest line, but I was worried: will people in Whiterun treat me differently after joining? For example, do the Companions become enemies, or will my wife Ysolda hate me?

Comment: related: [In Skyrim, are the Companion quests still available after taking over Whiterun (Stormcloaks path)?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/45005/in-skyrim-are-the-companion-quests-still-available-after-taking-over-whiterun)

Answer (score 1):

According tot his mod [Civil War Overhaul](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/37216/?) troops do not even care if you walk around in the other factions clothing. And guards did not care if your faction did not own the hold you where in.

I know this isn't 100% proof that 90% of the npcs do not care. But as the reactions had to be modded in, I doubt joining the civil war will have a real effect.

Note: yeah, the description of the mod is hard to read. Read between the lines and it will hopefully become clear what the modder changed, and thus, which things are NOT in the base game.

Answer (score 0):

They may say negative things (especially during the Civil War quests), but I believe that their aggression will not raise.

Source: Personal experience

Answer (score 0):

Some npcs will have negative greetings to you.  Some others npcs will have topics about the side that taken over the city like: "Is Whiterun better with the Stormcloaks?" Others don't mind about the Civil War.