# Can you cure lycanthropy after the companions quest line?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Has anyone actually cured lycanthropy?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35816/has-anyone-actually-cured-lycanthropy)

I still have four of the glenmoril witches heads but nothing happens when I click on the Flame of the Harbringer.

Answer (score 0):

I read that you have to cure the two brothers (being with V and F for their names but I cant remember the spellings off the top of my head) before you can cure yourself. Since you have that many heads left I would assume you have not done that yet.. This occurs when you cure the other person you had the quest for and then do not cure yourself immediately, you have to wait until they are done.