# I'm tired of being a werewolf, can I be cured?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Has anyone actually cured lycanthropy?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35816/has-anyone-actually-cured-lycanthropy)

How to get cured of werewolfism? I don't want to be werewolf anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to cure your lycanthropy after completing all of the "main" Companions quests, if you wish to do so.

Spoiler:

> It is done inside the Tomb of Ysgramor (same place you cure Kodlak), and I believe you need to be carrying an extra Glenmoril Witch head for yourself (you can get these during one of the quests).