# How can I cure Farkas and Vilkas after the purity test bugs out on Xbox 360?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

I know there is a bug with curing Vilkas of Lycanthropy before Farkas after I put myself in this, but somehow I think I just made it worse.

I was able to ask Vilkas four times about becoming cured and was able to kill his wolf spirit, but was not able to talk to Vilkas afterwards to finish the quest: the quest was finished before I had the chance to talk to him and now I'm not even able to have Farkas cured, even after doing a couple of quests for both Vilkas and Farkas.

Is there is a way to fix this on Xbox 360 so that both can be officially cured?

Comment: Hi Mike, welcome to Gaming.SE! We work a little differently from other gaming sites, and keep it to one question per... question. Check out "[Has anyone actually cured lycanthropy?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35816/has-anyone-actually-cured-lycanthropy)" which seems to confirm your suspicion that this is the correct way to cure lycanthropy without doing the Companions quest line.

Comment: I see. I do apologize for the confusion and I thank you for the help!